# How to see hidden source code of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there's pretty visualization at [big.dk](http://www.big.dk/#projects)

I tried to see the source code (tried with Chrome and Firefox) but it says:

```
You need to upgrade your browser to see ...
```

[image]

My browser are up to date. Somebody know what additional upgrade is need? Thank you!

(Or does somebody know how to draw something like that? Thank you!)

Comment: download the latest version? surely its not THAT complex???

Comment: my browsers are up to date... can you see the source code of the earth on that page?

Comment: "View source" in Chrome version 44.0.2403.130 m shows the source of that page.

Comment: @Blackwood thanks for trying it for me. I still got no luck:( see the screenshot I updated in the OP...

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version. Without any extra information, thats the best way. I or many stack-users can build that. This wont help you in any way!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Browser were already up to date... i was trying to get a general clue like "you can use the earth/map in D3 to do that, and use XXX to stake the icons up".